# angular2 ActivatedRoute showing Cannot resolve all parameters for Detail_retailer

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

i am using angular js 2.0.0 i am passing value through

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core"
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Users} from "../users/component"
import {Users_detail} from "../users_detail/component"

import {
    RouteConfig,RouterModule,
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
} from 'angular2/router';

@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/users', name: 'Users', component: Users},
    {path:'/users_detail/:id', name: 'Users_detail', component: User_retailer},
])
```

how do i get 'id' value in 'Users_detail'
users_detail.ts

```
import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from 'angular2/router';

constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {


}
```

showing error

"Cannot resolve all parameters for User_retailer(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations."

Answer (score 0):

Your component name is `Users_detail` as you imported:

`import {Users_detail} from "../users_detail/component"`

But in `RouteConfig` you've given `component: User_retailer`.

So, `RouteConfig` must be:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/users', name: 'Users', component: Users},
    {path:'/users_detail/:id', name: 'Users_detail', component: Users_detail},
    ])
```

And you can get `id`like this:

`let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying i change that but its also showing same error For
 " constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute)"